# Passing & changing control parameters (.Visible, .Text, etc) within a function

Tags: vb.net

I have a validation I run on multiple inputs on a page (checking valid dates on each date-entry textbox, for example).  I want to have a single function to pass the information into, instead of duplicating the same code across the whole page.

Right now, I have this:

```
Private Function HasDateError(ByRef dateErrorDiv As HtmlGenericControl, txtDate As TextBox) As Boolean
    dateErrorDiv.Visible = False

    If (date is not valid)
        dateErrorDiv.Visible = True
    Else
        txtDate.Text = Date.Parse(txtDate.Text)
        ' I know this seems silly, but it fixes problems where users enter a date in a weird format and don't know why it was wrong
    End If

    Return dateErrorDiv.Visible
End Function
```

The problem I'm having:

Despite passing ByRef, dateErrorDiv.Visible  and txtDate.Text aren't being updated by this code.

How do I pass controls (HtmlGenericControl, TextBox, etc) so I can update their properties (.Visible, .Text, etc) from within a function?

Edit: I have tried passing both as `ByVal` and `ByRef`, and I used a breakpoint to verify that the line `dateErrorDiv.Visible = True` is being hit, and that the value isn't changing.

As a test, I even simplified the function to the following (and again used breakpoints to verify that the value of .Visible never changed):

```
Private Function HasDateError(ByRef dateErrorDiv As HtmlGenericControl, txtDate As TextBox) As Boolean
    dateErrorDiv.Visible = False
    dateErrorDiv.Visible = True

    Return dateErrorDiv.Visible
End Function
```

Comment: Passing controls `ByRef` is too much for the purpose of only changing their properties, but it will work. Passing `ByVal` is the correct thing. But if it does not work with `ByRef`, your code either does not run at all, or there is some other code later that changes the properties back, or the code runs and changes properties but that does not look like you expect.

Comment: Create a new reference to an existing object rather than calling a direct reference to it..? But as @GSerg said, it should work anyway.

Comment: I switched it back to ByVal, but it still isn't working.

I verified the .Visible status by putting breakpoints in the code and checking the status as it runs through the function.  The lines to change .Visible are hit, but the actual value doesn't change.

Comment: What is `If (date is not valid)` supposed to do? note that you are missing the `Then` keyword, and no declaration or value for `date` is given in the code.